# In factorio can I control a belt from the logistics network?

Tags: factorio

It took me a long time to figure out that connecting a wire to a belt hooked it to the circuit network--  Now I'm wondering if there is a way to control it from a value from the logistics network.

I didn't see a "Connect to logistics network" dialog after connecting a wire to a transport belt so I'm guessing that if it's possible there is some additional trickery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, belts can't connect to the logistics network by themselves.

What you could do is put down a roboport and use the circuit network.

A roboport connected to the circuit network has two options:

- Emit the items in the logistics network (default)
- Emit statistics about bots in the logistics network

Connect a roboport to a belt and you can use regular circuit network conditions to enable/disable the belt as needed.